# Very important SQL performance queries - index building

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing

Hello i need several queries.

1- auto index suggestion query. dont tell me sql server profiler since it always fails because my sql server processes about 10000 query per second maybe more

2- performance degreading index finder query

3- duplicate index finder query

4- fragmantation rebuild query

thank you

Comment: I am having difficultly even understanding what your question is.... It might be better if you split each query you have as a separate question and elaborated a bit more on each question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't use a profiler maybe try using [statistics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190397.aspx). (I'm assuming MSSQL here)